# jacocoagent.jar missing in gradle 'clean build' phase

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, jacoco

I am facing an issue with gradle and jacoco where `gradle clean build` fails with `jacocoagent.jar` missing during tasks - `compileTestJava` and `Test`.

While examining the issue I found out that if I delete **build** folder under **.gradle** and run - `gradle build` or `gradle test` command, '*build*' folder gets created again and required '*jacocoagent.jar*' for codecoverage also gets created under '**/build/tmp/expandedArchives/**' location.

But if I run `gradle clean build` or `gradle clean test`, '*build*' folder gets deleted and created again but the '*expandedArchives*' folder under '*/build/tmp*' location doesn't get created and hence tests fails with below error -

> Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : build/tmp/expandedArchives/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.4.jar_7bfc4fd986d61dbf92065775ff3714a0/jacocoagent.jar

Here is the complete stacktrace for complieTestJava and Test tasks:

```
> Task :compileTestJava
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Could not write standard input to Gradle Test Executor 2.
java.io.IOException: The pipe is being closed
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.forwardContent(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.run(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

> Task :test
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : build/tmp/expandedArchives/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.4.jar_7bfc4fd986d61dbf92065775ff3714a0/jacocoagent.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : build/tmp/expandedArchives/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.4.jar_7bfc4fd986d61dbf92065775ff3714a0/jacocoagent.jar

Could not write standard input to Gradle Test Executor 3.
java.io.IOException: The pipe is being closed
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.forwardContent(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.run(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any leads what could be going wrong here?

Below are the details of my build environment:

> - Gradle   - 5.6.2
> - Jacoco   - 0.8.4
> - Java     - 1.8.0.181
> - IntelliJ - 2019.2.3 (Ultimate Edition)
> - OS       - Windows 7 Enterprise

## Build Script

I can not add entire build script here but below are the tasks which are related to jacoco:

```
jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.4"
}
test {
    exclude "features/**"
    exclude "**/*IntegrationTests*"
}
jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination file("${buildDir}/jacocoHtml")
    }
}

jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
    violationRules {
        rule {
            limit {
                counter = 'LINE'
                value = 'COVEREDRATIO'
                minimum = 0.75
            }
        }
    }
}

jacocoTestCoverageVerification.mustRunAfter jacocoTestReport

test.finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
```

Comment: Could you please attach your build script?

Comment: Updated my question with jacoco tasks.

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce the issue with new sample project?

Comment: With a very basic spring-boot project it worked fine. Now I will have to build it brick-by-brick and see for which dependency it is failing.